# SharePoint and Outlook Integration

Tags: outlook

I know SharePoint has a great integration with outlook but we are looking into a plug in that lets you browse SharePoint content directly from outlook and lets you store emails into SharePoint and assign appropriate meta data to that email item.

We have found a software that does just that:

http://www.workshare.com/products/point/sharepoint-outlook-connect-features.aspx

I was wondering if you guys know of any other software does the same or better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I've used [harmon.ie](http://harmon.ie/) in the past and found it to be better than sliced bread.  Maybe even as good as peanut butter toast, but that may be pushing it.

Answer (score 3):

The capability to save emails from Outlook to SharePoint and to browse SharePoint within Outlook is provided by OnePlaceMail.  You can also drag and drop email attachments into SharePoint and automatically capture the email attributes in the same manner as emails.

The following video provides a 5 minute demonstration: http://www.scinaptic.com/oneplacemail-sharepoint-video-demonstration.html and you are welcome to download the full OnePlaceMail software for a trial by going to http://www.scinaptic.com/oneplacemail-features.html

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look [SharePoint Outlook Integration](http://bit.ly/gQTpKf). It provides email and attachment drag and drop to SharePoint; Meta data mapping and others.